# JavaScript mouse position recording is longer than supposed to - what causes delay?

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk

I have a javascript on amazon mTurk that records the mouse position over a canvas, every 0.5s, starting from when they click and music starts to play.

I noticed that some of my mouse recordings, are slightly longer (and even shorter) than they are supposed to. I am assuming that some sort of delay is popping up in my script, but at the back of the song, start or random times? Any ideas what may be causing this?

My best idea so far is to not only save the mouse positions, but also the timestamp, although that seems like overhead!

```
    <div id="song_4">
        <br>
        <h4>Question 4</h4>
        <p>Please click the center of the graph to start the music. Your mouse position will be recorded, so please <b>continuously</b> indicate your perceived emotion in terms of: </p>
        <ul>
        <li><b>Valence</b> relates to the emotion conveyed by the music, and falls on a scale from positive to negative. </li>
        <br>
        <li><b>Arousal</b> relates to the energy level conveyed by the music, and falls on a scale from high to low.</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <audio id='music_4'>
                    <source id='source_4' type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <canvas id='canvas_4'></canvas>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col_auto">
                    <progress id='progress_4' value="0" max="100"></progress>
                </div>
                <div class="col_auto">
                    <p id = 'timeleft_4'>-00:00</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <input class="form-control" id="valences_4" name="valences_4" size="10" type="text" readonly  />
                    <input class="form-control" id="arousals_4" name="arousals_4" size="10" type="text" readonly  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<script>
var finished = 0;
var random_indices=[];
var random_deam=[]




class MyCanvas{
    constructor(indexID, callback) {
        let _this = this;
        let canvasid = 'canvas_'+indexID;
        let musicid = 'music_' +indexID;
        let progressid = 'progress_' + indexID;
        let timeleftid = 'timeleft_' +indexID;
        let valencesid = 'valences_' +indexID;
        let arousalsid = 'arousals_' +indexID;

        this.canvas      = document.getElementById(canvasid);
        this.progress    = document.getElementById(progressid);
        this.timeleft    = document.getElementById(timeleftid);
        this.ctx         = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.ctxWidth    = 500;
        this.ctxHeight   = 500;
        this.chartWidth  = 360;
        this.chartHeight = 360;
        this.marginX = (this.ctxWidth - this.chartWidth)/2
        this.marginY = (this.ctxHeight - this.chartHeight)/2
        this.mouseX = this.ctxWidth/2;
        this.mouseY = this.ctxHeight/2;
        this.outputX = 0;
        this.outputY = 0;
        this.startPlaying = false;
        this.endPlaying = false;
        this.music = document.getElementById(musicid);
        this.recorder = null;
        this.valences = [0];
        this.arousals = [0];
        this.canvas.setAttribute('width', this.ctxWidth);
        this.canvas.setAttribute('height', this.ctxHeight);
        document.getElementById(valencesid).style.visibility='hidden';
        document.getElementById(arousalsid).style.visibility='hidden';

        this.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            var mousePos = _this.getMousePos(_this.canvas,evt);
            if (mousePos.x > _this.ctxWidth/2-10 && mousePos.x < _this.ctxWidth/2+10 && mousePos.y < _this.ctxHeight/2+10 && mousePos.y > _this.ctxHeight/2-10 && !_this.startPlaying) {
              _this.startPlaying=true;
              _this.startRecord();
              _this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
                  var mousePos = _this.getMousePos(_this.canvas,evt);
                  if (mousePos.x >= _this.marginX && mousePos.x <= _this.ctxWidth-_this.marginX && mousePos.y >= _this.marginY && mousePos.y <= _this.ctxHeight-_this.marginY && _this.startPlaying) {
                      _this.mouseX = mousePos.x;
                      _this.mouseY = mousePos.y;
                      _this.outputX = (mousePos.x-_this.ctxWidth/2) / (_this.chartWidth/2);
                      _this.outputY = -(mousePos.y-_this.ctxHeight/2) / (_this.chartHeight/2);
                      console.log(_this.outputX,_this.outputY);
                  }
                  _this.redraw(_this.ctx, _this.ctxWidth,_this.ctxHeight,_this.marginX,_this.marginY,_this.chartWidth,_this.chartHeight,_this.startPlaying,_this.endPlaying);
              })
              _this.redraw(_this.ctx, _this.ctxWidth,_this.ctxHeight,_this.marginX,_this.marginY,_this.chartWidth,_this.chartHeight,_this.startPlaying,_this.endPlaying);
            }
            }, true)
        this.redraw(_this.ctx, _this.ctxWidth,_this.ctxHeight,_this.marginX,_this.marginY,_this.chartWidth,_this.chartHeight,_this.startPlaying,_this.endPlaying);

        this.music.onended = function() {
            clearInterval(_this.recorder);
            _this.endPlaying=true;
            console.log(_this.valences);
            console.log(_this.arousals);

            $( "#"+valencesid).attr('value',_this.valences.join(','));
            $( "#"+arousalsid ).attr('value',_this.arousals.join(','));
            if (callback !== null) {
                callback();
            }

        };


        // Assign an ontimeupdate event to the <video> element, and execute a function if the current playback position has changed
        this.music.ontimeupdate = function() {_this.changeProgress(_this.music, _this.progress,_this.timeleft)};


    }


    drawXaxis(ctx,marginX,marginY,width, height) {
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle='#01b9f5'

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0+marginX,height/2+marginY);
        ctx.lineTo(width+marginX, height/2+marginY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // Rewrite to handle variable dimensions.
    drawXscale(ctx,marginX,marginY,width,height) {
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.strokeStyle='#d2d2d2'
        let unitLen = height/20

        // Render loop
        for (var i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {
            if (i==10) {
                continue;
            }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0+marginX,unitLen*i+marginY);
            ctx.lineTo(width+marginX,unitLen*i+marginY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        // Condition to check scale size to prevent overdraw?

    }

    drawYaxis(ctx,marginX,marginY,width, height) {
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle='#01b9f5'

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(width/2+marginX,0+marginY);
        ctx.lineTo(width/2+marginX,height+marginY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }


    drawYscale(ctx,marginX,marginY,width, height) {
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.strokeStyle='#d2d2d2'
        let unitLen = width/20

        // Render loop
        for (var i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {
            if (i==10) {
                continue;
            }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(unitLen*i+marginX,0+marginY);
            ctx.lineTo(unitLen*i+marginX,height+marginY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    drawLabels(ctx,marginX, marginY, width, height) {
        ctx.font = "20px Arial";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom'
        ctx.fillText("Arousal(+)",width/2,marginY-5);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.fillText("Arousal(-)", width/2, height-marginY+5);

        ctx.textAlign = 'left';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'center';
        ctx.fillText("Valence", width-marginX, height/2-15);
        ctx.fillText("(+)", width-marginX, height/2+15);

        ctx.textAlign = 'right';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'center';
        ctx.fillText("Valence", marginX, height/2-15);
        ctx.fillText("(-)", marginX, height/2+15);

    }

    drawBorder(ctx,marginX,marginY, width, height) {
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle='#000000';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(marginX,marginY,width-marginX*2,height-marginY*2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    drawPoint(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,outputX,outputY){
        ctx.strokeStyle='#000000';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center'
        ctx.fillRect(mouseX-5, mouseY-5, 10, 10);
        ctx.fillText('V'+outputX.toFixed(1)+',A'+outputY.toFixed(1), mouseX, mouseY+10);

    }

    drawPlayButton(ctx,ctxWidth,ctxHeight) {
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle='#000000';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(ctxWidth/2-8,ctxHeight/2+8);
        ctx.lineTo(ctxWidth/2-8,ctxHeight/2-8);
        ctx.lineTo(ctxWidth/2+8,ctxHeight/2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.fillText("Click the button to start the audio", ctxWidth/2, ctxHeight/2+15);
    }
    drawEndMessage(ctx,ctxWidth,ctxHeight) {
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.strokeStyle='#000000';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillText("You have finished this question", ctxWidth/2, ctxHeight/2+15);
    }

    getMousePos(canvas, evt){
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }

    startRecord(){
        this.music.play();
        let _this = this;
        this.recorder = setInterval(function() {
            _this.valences.push(_this.outputX);
            _this.arousals.push(_this.outputY);
        }, 100)
    }
    redraw(ctx, ctxWidth,ctxHeight,marginX,marginY,chartWidth,chartHeight,startPlaying,endPlaying){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctxWidth,ctxHeight)
        this.drawXaxis(ctx,marginX,marginY,chartHeight,chartWidth);
        this.drawYaxis(ctx,marginX,marginY,chartHeight,chartWidth);
        this.drawXscale(ctx,marginX,marginY,chartHeight,chartWidth);
        this.drawYscale(ctx,marginX,marginY,chartHeight, chartWidth);

        this.drawLabels(ctx,marginX, marginY, ctxWidth, ctxHeight);
        this.drawBorder(ctx,marginX, marginY, ctxWidth, ctxHeight);
        if (!startPlaying && !endPlaying){
            this.drawPlayButton(ctx,ctxWidth,ctxHeight);
        } else if (startPlaying && !endPlaying){
            this.drawPoint(ctx,this.mouseX,this.mouseY,this.outputX,this.outputY);
        } else{
            this.drawEndMessage(ctx,ctxWidth,ctxHeight)
        }

    }


    changeProgress(music, progress,timeleft) {
    // Display the current position of the video in a <p> element with id="demo"
        progress.setAttribute('value',music.currentTime/music.duration*100);
        var min = Math.floor((music.duration - music.currentTime)/60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(music.duration -  music.currentTime) %60;
        timeleft.innerHTML= "-"+min.toString()+':'+seconds.toString();
    }
}



function clearPage(){
    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName("my-page");
    length = pages.length;
    var index = 0;
    for (index=0; index < length; index++) {
        pages[index].style.display = "none";
    }
}

function checkFirstPage(){
    let e = document.getElementById('age');
    if(e.value=="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("gender");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value =="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("fav-music-language");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value =="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("country-live");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value =="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("country-enculturation");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value =="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("genre");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value =="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("training");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value =="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("play-instrument");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value =="") return false;
    e = document.getElementById("understood");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].text =="No") return false;
    return true;
}

function nextPage(){
    clearPage();
    fired = event.target.id;
    number = fired.substring(fired.length - 1, fired.length);
    number = parseInt(number);
    document.getElementById("tag"+number.toString()).className=document.getElementById("tag"+number.toString()).className.replace("active", "");
    document.getElementById("page"+(number+1).toString()).style.display='block';
    document.getElementById("tag"+(number+1).toString()).className += ' active';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

function clearCanvas(){
    for (index=2; index<=24; index++){
        document.getElementById("canvas_"+index).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}


function getRandom(wanted, total){
    let result = [];
    let i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<wanted;i++){
        while(true){
            random = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
            if (result.includes(random)== false){
                result.push(random);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}

function showSubmit(){
    let total = random_indices.length + 4
    finished = finished+1;
    console.log(finished)
    console.log(total)
    if (finished<total){
        document.getElementById("canvas_"+(finished+1)).style.visibility='visible';
    }
    if (finished>=total){
        document.getElementById("submitButton").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
function reduceMusic(){
    let total = 0;
    let index = 0;
    while(index<24){
        total +=document.getElementById("music_"+(index+1)).duration;
        console.log(document.getElementById("music_"+(index+1)).duration);
        if (total>60*30){
            break;
        }
        index = index +1;
    }
    let i = 1
    for (i = index+1; i <= 24; i ++){
        document.getElementById("song_"+i).style.display='none';
        random_indices.pop()
    }
    console.log(random_indices);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("submitButton").style.visibility = "hidden";

    clearPage();
    clearCanvas();
    document.getElementById("page1").style.display='block';
    $('#continue2').on('click', nextPage);
    $('#continue3').on('click', nextPage);

    $('#continue1').on('click',function(event){
        if (!checkFirstPage()){
            var node = document.createElement("h5");
            node.style.color='red'                 
            var textnode = document.createTextNode("You need to answer all questions and confirm yes in the last question.");         // Create a text node
            node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
            document.getElementById("page1").appendChild(node); 
        } else{
            nextPage();
        }
    })

    trial = new MyCanvas('trial',function(){
        $("#continue3").removeAttr('hidden');
    });
    var music_all = document.getElementById("music_all").value;
    // var music_all = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/35.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/145.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/275.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/366.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/661.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/695.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/702.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/839.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/882.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/00/883.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/71.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/139.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/143.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/154.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/175.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/177.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/228.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/333.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/890.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/01/897.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/93.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/130.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/150.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/216.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/243.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/288.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/404.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/487.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/828.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/10/942.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/209.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/411.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/427.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/459.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/505.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/528.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/648.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/693.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/748.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/11/801.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/33.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/46.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/58.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/62.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/80.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/85.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/90.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/102.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/184.mp3;https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/musicemotion/0505/199.mp3';
    // var music_all = 'SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3';


    var music_list = music_all.split(';');

    var deam_music_all = document.getElementById("deam_music_all").value;
    // var deam_music_all = 'SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3;SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3'


    var deam_music_list = deam_music_all.split(';');

    console.log(music_list.length)
    random_indices = getRandom(20, music_list.length);
    random_deam = getRandom(4,4);
    console.log(random_indices)
    console.log(random_deam)

    $('#source_1').attr("src",deam_music_list[random_deam[0]]);
    document.getElementById("music_1").load();
    test1 = new MyCanvas('1',showSubmit);

    $('#source_4').attr("src",deam_music_list[random_deam[1]]);
    document.getElementById("music_4").load();
    test4 = new MyCanvas('4',showSubmit);

    $('#source_7').attr("src",deam_music_list[random_deam[2]]);
    document.getElementById("music_7").load();
    test7 = new MyCanvas('7',showSubmit);

    $('#source_10').attr("src",deam_music_list[random_deam[3]]);
    document.getElementById("music_10").load();
    test10 = new MyCanvas('10',showSubmit);

    $('#source_2').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[5-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_2").load();
    test2 = new MyCanvas('2',showSubmit);

    $('#source_3').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[6-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_3").load();
    test3 = new MyCanvas('3',showSubmit);
    $('#source_5').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[7-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_5").load();
    test5 = new MyCanvas('5',showSubmit);

    $('#source_6').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[8-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_6").load();
    test6 = new MyCanvas('6',showSubmit);

    $('#source_8').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[9-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_8").load();
    test8 = new MyCanvas('8',showSubmit);

    $('#source_9').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[10-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_9").load();
    test9 = new MyCanvas('9',showSubmit);

    $('#source_11').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[11-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_11").load();
    test11 = new MyCanvas('11',showSubmit);

    $('#source_12').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[12-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_12").load();
    test12 = new MyCanvas('12',showSubmit);

    $('#source_13').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[13-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_13").load();
    test13 = new MyCanvas('13',showSubmit);

    $('#source_14').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[14-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_14").load();
    test14 = new MyCanvas('14',showSubmit);

    $('#source_15').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[15-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_15").load();
    test15 = new MyCanvas('15',showSubmit);

    $('#source_16').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[16-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_16").load();
    test16 = new MyCanvas('16',showSubmit);

    $('#source_17').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[17-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_17").load();
    test17 = new MyCanvas('17',showSubmit);

    $('#source_18').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[18-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_18").load();
    test18 = new MyCanvas('18',showSubmit);

    $('#source_19').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[19-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_19").load();
    test19 = new MyCanvas('19',showSubmit);

    $('#source_20').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[20-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_20").load();
    test20 = new MyCanvas('20',showSubmit);

    $('#source_21').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[21-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_21").load();
    test21 = new MyCanvas('21',showSubmit);

    $('#source_22').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[22-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_22").load();
    test22 = new MyCanvas('22',showSubmit);

    $('#source_23').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[23-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_23").load();
    test23 = new MyCanvas('23',showSubmit);

    $('#source_24').attr("src",music_list[random_indices[24-5]]);
    document.getElementById("music_24").load();
    test24 = new MyCanvas('24',showSubmit);

    setTimeout(reduceMusic, 300000);

    $( "#random_indices").attr('value',random_indices.join(','));
    document.getElementById("random_indices").style.visibility='hidden';

    $( "#random_deam_indices").attr('value',random_deam.join(','));
    document.getElementById("random_deam_indices").style.visibility='hidden';


});

</script>
```

Comment: Is the audio file preloaded?

Comment: Probably not, how would I do that? If this is not the case, I assume I should cut off the data in the beginning?

Comment: It's just a hunch, but maybe there's a delay because the file is not playing immediately.

Comment: How would I go about to buffer the audio, is that even possible?